# Complex analysis, inverse conjugate function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disk $D$ with the center $0$. Now, assume that $f$ is non-vanishing.

Now, I want to show that $\frac{1}{{\bar{f}}(1/{\bar{z}})}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}-\bar{D}$. I think the Morera's theorem is hint. How can I show that?

Comment: I don't think using Morera's theorem is a very good choice here. Do you know that for a holomorphic $g$ the function $w \mapsto \overline{g(\overline{w})}$ is also holomorphic? Can you modify the argument to apply to the function $w \mapsto \overline{g(1/\overline{w})}$?

Comment: Is the function $\omega \mapsto {\bar{\bar{\omega}}}$ holomorphic ? I searched the anti-holomorphic properties. But, I can't figure out that.

Comment: Well, $\overline{\overline{\omega}} = \omega$.

Comment: Yeah, double conjugate is always itself. But, I want to know how it operates on the function $g$.

Comment: You mentioned the term "anti-holomorphic". What do you know about compositions of a) holomorphic and anti-holomorphic functions, and b) anti-holomorphic and anti-holomorphic functions?

Comment: $f(z)$ is said to be anti-holomorphic if and only if $f(\bar{z} )$ is holomorphic. Am I right?

Comment: There are several equivalent characterisations. This is one of them. Which of them is used as the definition depends on the author.